# Unable to investigate on ZEIT Now 502 eror for a NextJS app

Tags: mongodb, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, vercel

I'm investigating by days with no results about this exception that my *NextJS* app is currently throwing, in particular when I try to open a single specific URL:

> 502: BAD_GATEWAY
>   Code: NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_FUNCTION
>   ID: zrh1:4zx5l-1572269318137-64d401b5d058

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Basically, I have on https://lucacattide.dev/about/en a page that this app should open. This is linked to a *MongoDB* third-party cloud API platform - [*Squidex*](https://squidex.io) - which is responsible to populate the page itself, via *GraphQL* queries. The app uses *Apollo* as GraphQL client. The app instead, is hosted on [*ZEIT.co*](http://ZEIT.co) serverless cloud, with *Now* 2.0 version.

During the development process, everything works fine. The page loads up and data is fetched in the right way. Notice that for development, I'm working on `now-dev` environment instead of a custom *Express* server, in order to reproduce the `production` one, as suggested by ZEIT itself.

The exception is being thrown on the `production` environment - the live one on the hosting platform, not on `localhost`; the main problem is that no errors are being shown on live logs or local development. So I'm literally going mad in inspecting the possible cause.

I've already tried to test the involved page, by splitting it in sections and trying to exclude child components, or focusing the inspection on the GraphQL query. But the first hasn't produced results and the latter works fine in every environment.

As last try, I deleted and re-created the back-end contents related to that page, because in the past I had a similar issue due to an old GraphQL edited schema that didn't reflected its modifications through the API - so in that case I was still receiving 502 errors. But this time it didn't worked.

Anyone could help me to understand what's going on, please?

Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: By live logs did you mean in the Zeit.co's runtime logs? Not a single indicator of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by an incompatibility between the [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) library and the `Now` environment.
By replacing it with the [react-wordcloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wordcloud) one, the error has been solved.

Thanks everyone for your assistance.

Comment: how did you spot the issue? I'm having the same error and there are no indications in the logs. just auth/network-request-failed.

Comment: Hi @pseudozach, I was forced to isolate one by one my app child components, in order to spot which one was related to it and understand in which way its dependencies were involved. When I excluded from deploy the guilty one, the exception has been dismissed. In your case, if you experiencing an ```auth``` related, probably it could depends by a wrong header request setting, such as missing ``Bearer <TOKEN>``` and so on. I suggest you to investigate in that direction, if you didn't. Here you can find indications about ```Now``` exception codes: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/network/status-codes/

Comment: For others who land here in the future, debugging locally with `now dev` produces more helpful logging for troubleshooting purposes.